# Top hitting IPs on my Google Compute engine instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver, ddos

Any `Stackdriver monitoring metric` available to identify the top hitting `IP Addresses` on my `Google Compute engine instances` or `Google Load Balancer Service` .
Any other native `GCP` tool available which can help me to gather such reports.

This will help me to block any `IP addresses` sending malicious traffic

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor/) for reporting and blocking malicious traffic.

You *could* enable [firewall rule logging](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewall-rules-logging) and create a logs-based metric for the rule(s) you're interested in, but this is only practical if you have a few IPs sending malicious traffic.
An example metric can be created with [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/metrics/create) with a JSON config file such as:

```
{
  "name": "<myCustomMetric>",
  "filter": "logName:(projects/<projectID>/logs/compute.googleapis.com%2Ffirewall) AND jsonPayload.rule_details.reference:(\"network:<vpcName>/firewall:<firewallRule>\")\njsonPayload.disposition=\"ALLOWED\"",
  "labelExtractors": {
    "Source": "EXTRACT(jsonPayload.connection.src_ip)"
  },
  "metricDescriptor": {
    "labels": [
      {
        "key": "<sourceIP>"
      }
    ],
    "metricKind": "DELTA",
    "name": "projects/<projectID>/metricDescriptors/logging.googleapis.com/user/<myCustomMetric>",
    "type": "logging.googleapis.com/user/<myCustomMetric>",
    "unit": "1",
    "valueType": "INT64"
  },
}
```

Where :

- `<myCustomMetric>` is the name you want for your metric
- `<projectID>` is your project ID
- `<vpcName>` is your VPC network name
- `<firewallRule>` is you VPC firewall rule name
- `<sourceIP>` is the label you want for the incoming IP address

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Cloud SDK** with the command `gcloud compute addresses list - list addresses`  to get that list, as the following [Official GCP’s Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/addresses/list) says. Examples:

```
$ gcloud compute addresses list --uri
$ gcloud compute addresses list --global
$ gcloud compute addresses list --filter=region:us-central1
```

A second option is to set up an Uptime Check following this url’s [steps](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/docs/samples/monitoring-uptime-check-create) and then verify the List uptime-check server IP addresses, as the following [enter link description here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks/using-uptime-checks#get-ips) indicates. Here is an example of the code to create the Uptime Check:

```
public static object CreateUptimeCheck(string projectId, string hostName,
    string displayName)
{
    // Define a new config.
    var config = new UptimeCheckConfig()
    {
        DisplayName = displayName,
        MonitoredResource = new MonitoredResource()
        {
            Type = "uptime_url",
            Labels = { { "host", hostName } }
        },
        HttpCheck = new UptimeCheckConfig.Types.HttpCheck()
        {
            Path = "/",
            Port = 80,
        },
        Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10).ToDuration(),
        Period = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).ToDuration()
    };
    // Create a client.
    var client = UptimeCheckServiceClient.Create();
    ProjectName projectName = new ProjectName(projectId);
    // Create the config.
    var newConfig = client.CreateUptimeCheckConfig(
        projectName,
        config,
        CallSettings.FromExpiration(
            Expiration.FromTimeout(
                TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2))));
    Console.WriteLine(newConfig.Name);
    return 0;
}
```

And the steps to list the IP addresses, once the **Uptime Check** is running:

In the **Cloud Console**, select **Monitoring** or click the following button.
In the navigation pane, select **Uptime checks**.
In the **Uptime checks** menu, click **Download get_app**. A file uptime-source-ips.txt is downloaded and contains the **IP addresses**.

There is no monitoring tool available right now inside of **Cloud Monitoring** yet.